# Problema creando un nuevo DIV con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Tengo un problema. Tengo que crear un nuevo div dentro de otro div y no estoy logrando hacerlo. Tengo un formulario donde completo un par de datos, pongo continuar y se tendría que crear el DIV.

El problema que tengo es que cuando abro la pagina, y completo el formulario que tengo para crear el DIV, es como que el DIV aparece, me muestra el cartel que el div se creo y desaparece rapidamente. De hecho es como si toda la pagina hiciera F5. Luego, completo el formulario nuevamente y funciona. Es decir, en el primer ingreso no esta funcionando, la pagina hace como un F5 y cuando completo todo devuelta, funciona sin problemas.

El HTML es:

```
 <div class="contenido">
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="publicaciones">
    <img src="img/producto.jpg">
    <button class="active">COMPRAR</button>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

La función de JS es la siguiente:

```
function crear()
{
var padre = document.getElementsByClassName("contenido");
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.className="publicaciones";
var div2 = document.createElement("div");
div2.className="responsive";
div2.appendChild(div);
padre[0].prepend(div2);

window.alert("Producto Creado");

}
```

Después solo tengo el formulario donde en el input pongo onclick="crear()".

Comment: al parecer el div se agrega pero aparece arriba de todo sin estilos, pero desaparecer no desaparece. Si vas a consola > elementos y miras el div esta ahi donde lo pusiste

Comment: Lo busque ahí y no esta.

Answer (score 0):

Error mio. El type submit en el formulario estaba haciendo que todo se borre.

Comment: si, la pagina se recarga si el boton es type="submit". En todo caso si no queres que se recargue la pagina cuando le haces click al boton,  dentro del evento podes poner event.preventDEfault() y justamente se previene el comportamiento por defecto del boton, sino le pones type="button" y ya no se recarga